# Get a String from a Map inside Map Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, hashmap

What do you think is the best way to find a value in a map inside another map.

```
    Map <String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();

    map1.put("map1|1", "1.1");
    map1.put("map1|2", "1.2");
    map1.put("map1|3", "1.3");
    map1.put("map1|4", "1.4");

    Map <String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();

    map2.put("map2|1", "2.1");
    map2.put("map2|2", "2.2");
    map2.put("map2|3", "2.3");
    map2.put("map2|4", "2.4");


    Map<String, Map> mapOfMaps = new HashMap<>();

    mapOfMaps.put("MAP|map1", map1);
    mapOfMaps.put("MAP|map2", map2);
```

Now if I need the value of "MAP|map2" (inside mapOfMaps) and "map2|3" (inside map2) will be "2.3"

I tried to do something like:

```
System.out.println("x="+getValue(mapOfMaps,"MAP|map2", "map2|4"));

public static String getValue (Map<String, Map> map,String mapfind, String val) {

     Map<Object, Object> mp = map.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getKey().equals(mapfind))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));

     System.out.println("--------"+mp);

     return (String) mp.get(val);
 }
```

but the result is:

```
--------{MAP|map2={map2|1=2.1, map2|4=2.4, map2|2=2.2, map2|3=2.3}}
x=null
```

Can you help me with some ideas?

Comment: Why not just `map.get(mapfind).get(val)`? You'll want to check for nulls of course.

Comment: `Map<String, Map>` is using a *raw* `Map`. DO NOT use *raw* generics!! Complete the definition, i.e. `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`

Comment: instead of map of map try to use  https://www.baeldung.com/guava-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of declaring `mapOfMaps` by its [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) it should be defined as

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapOfMaps = new HashMap<>();
```

The corresponding `getValue` method would look like this:

```
  public static String getValue(Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapOfMaps, String mapfind, String val) {
    Map<String, String> innerMap = mapOfMaps.get(mapfind);
    return innerMap != null ?
      innerMap.get(val) :
      null;
  }
```

Using `Optional` we can write it as follows:

```
  public static String getValue(Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapOfMaps, String mapfind, String val) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(mapOfMaps.get(mapfind))
      .map(m -> m.get(val))
      .orElse(null);
  }
```

If we kept `mapOfMaps` declared by its raw type we would get in the first version of `getValue` a type safety warning about an [unchecked conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9) and in the second version we would need explicitly cast the result to `String`. Since we use `mapOfMaps` only to map `String` keys to `String` values we should declare it accordingly.

---

Further reading: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Thanks this answer works fine!!, and I update the raw type!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to get your desired output would be to use `map.get(mapfind).get(val)`. But if you want to achieve it using your existing code, you could call `values()` on the collected `map` and call filter to get a second level filter. Below is the code snippet of your modified method

```
public static String getValue(Map<String, Map> map, String mapfind, String val) {
    Map mp = map.entrySet().stream().filter(x -> x.getKey().equals(mapfind))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()))

            .values().stream().filter(y -> y.containsKey(val)).findAny().orElse(null);

    System.out.println("--------" + mp);
    if (mp == null)
        return "";
    return (String) mp.get(val);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static String getValue (Map<String, Map> map,String mapfind, String val) {
    Map childMap = map.get(mapfind);
    if (childMap == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return childMap.containsKey(val) ? childMap.get(val).toString() : null;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52227886/get-a-string-from-a-map-inside-map-java-8#comment91405344_52227886

Comment: At least replace `findMap` by `mapfind` so your code can be compiled.